# Plotting two functions values in two axis

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have two multivariate functions $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$. I want a plot in which in the horizontal axis I have the values of $f_1$ in a specific point $(a,b)$ and on the vertical axis I have the value of $f_2$ in the same point $(a,b)$. I tried storing the values of the functions in two lists and plot them, but it would be nice to be able to avoid this solution.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]`

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I tried the parametric plot suggested by Bob Hanlon, but that code produces a region. I also tried

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{f1[x,a],f2[x,a]}, {x, 0, 1}],{a,0,1}]

But it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: you said multivariate, but also the "values" of $f_1$ at a specific point; did you happen to mean multivalued, or was "values" the typo?